# Access previous row value in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have four columns in table1 in MySQL (Date, Open, High, Low, Close, 
Calculation). I am trying to figure out a way to create a trigger such that when ever a new value is updated in table 1, the **Calculation** field gets updated using previous rows value. I am currently using the below trigger to update **Calculation** field using **current** High, **current** Low and **current** close

```
DELIMITER //
create TRIGGER `updatetable1` before insert ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW begin
    set NEW.Calculation=((NEW.High-New.Low)*0.118)+NEW.Close;
   end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I would like to modify the formula a little bit using the following logic :

```
Calculation (i) =((High(i-1) -Low(i-1))*0.118)+Close(i-1);
```

How could I access the **previous** row value's of High, Low and Close in this trigger to update **current** row value of Calculation ?

Example:

[image]

Comment: You appear to be aware of `NEW` but not of `OLD`. From the manual: "Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated. "

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: I wrote the logic as below:

 set NEW.Calculation=((OLD.High-OLD.Low)*0.118)+OLD.Close;


and it shows me the following error:
Error Code: 1363. There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you were writing an UPDATE trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite your trigger as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

create TRIGGER `updatetable1` before insert ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW 
begin
    declare prev_low float;
    declare prev_high float;
    declare prev_close float;

    select   low, high, close
    into     prev_low, prev_high, prev_close 
    from     table1
    order by date desc
    limit 1;

    set NEW.Calculation=(prev_high-prev_low)*0.118 + prev_close;
end//

DELIMITER ;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b499a/1)

Change the datatype of `prev_low` (and other variables) to whichever datatype you use in your table.

Comment: I am getting the following error :

CREATE TRIGGER `updatetable1` before insert ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW  begin     declare prev_low float Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: That is probably related to the delimiter you use. Check the fiddle: you can see it works (I set the delimiter to `//`).

Comment: For clarification I added the delimiter modifying statements before and after the trigger in my answer just now. As you already had them, I did not provide them in my original version, but apparently you did not keep them...